# Trouble during passing extension data along with session request in QuickBlox

Tags: javascript, ios, video, webrtc, quickblox

I am working on a project which provides video calling from web to phone (iOS or Android). I am using QuickBlox + WebRTC to implement video calling. From web I want to pass some additional info along with call request like caller name, etc. I looked into the JavaScript documentation of QuickBlox + WebRTC which suggest to use the following code (JavaScript):

```
var array = {
                me: "Hari Gangadharan",
            }

QB.webrtc.call(callee.id, 'video', array);
```

I have implemented the same code but unable to get the info attached with session request on the receiver side (getting nil reference in iOS method).

```
- (void)didReceiveNewSession:(QBRTCSession *)session userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
//Here userInfo is always nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following structure

```
var array = {
  "userInfo": {
     "me":"Hari Gangadharan",
  }
}
```

because our iOS SDK uses "userInfo" as a key for parsing custom user info

Check [Signaling v1.0](http://quickblox.com/developers/VideoChat)